# Error by importing Lucene LongField in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, lucene

I use lucene 6.2.1 on eclipse but get error when I import LongFeild.
this is my importing part of code:

```
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Field;
import org.apache.lucene.document.LongField;
import org.apache.lucene.document.StringField;
import org.apache.lucene.document.TextField;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig;
import org.apache.lucene.index.Term;
import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory;
import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.FileVisitResult;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.SimpleFileVisitor;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;
import java.util.Date;
```

and the only line which gives me error is

```
import org.apache.lucene.document.LongField;
```

I added lucene-core-6.2.1.jar", lucene-queryparser-6.2.1.jar", and lucene analyzers-common-6.2.1.jar" to my project.
What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In Lucene 6.2.1, there is a LegacyLongField, which is marked deprecated and recommends to make use of LongPoint instead.

LegacyLongField

http://lucene.apache.org/core/6_2_1/core/org/apache/lucene/document/LegacyLongField.html

LongPoint

http://lucene.apache.org/core/6_2_1/core/org/apache/lucene/document/LongPoint.html

Full API listing

http://lucene.apache.org/core/6_2_1/core/index.html

Comment: Does it do exactly same as LongField?

Comment: LegacyLongField works the same as LongField.  It was just renamed, repackaged.  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-6917.  The implementation for LongPoint is very different..  It may require you to upgrade your index.